# Cannot create new items beside editorconfig file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, config, text-editor

I did some optimizations for VS 2017 (removed insight extension and did some changes in the options).

I also updated to the latest VS 2017 version.

Now I am getting a very weird issue, I managed to solve it by rebuilding the solution and removing the .sou file earlier but now it ain't working anymore.

Whenever I am trying to open a new item ( mostly a cs class ) I am getting instead the following menu -

[image]

Those are the only items I can create.

I don't know if it is relevant but I think this issue began happening after I did few minor tweaks at the text editor options ( something about the vertical and horizontal scroll bars).

I also disabled and enabled Resharper.

Honestly I am a bit clueless about the reasoning for having this issue and any help with finding a solution will be must appreciated!

Edit: I now noticed that it only happens in the .Net core 2.0 console (MVC/API) project, my other projects are fine (.net core class library projects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After figuring out it was related to specific project type it was a bit easier to track the source of the problem. 
It seems that when I updated to the latest version it didnt include the packages which needed for web development ( api,mvc etc... ).

Once I added those packages back via VS install tool (simply checking the needed checkbox for web development ) it went back to working fine.

So I guess the editor config file was the only option I had because that existing project type was not recognized by VS after my update because it simply lacked the needed packages to recognize and work with it.